# Linking thumbnail to full size image

Tags: functions, post-thumbnails

I use a function in my blog (getImage) to call thumbnails in the loop (it calls the 1st image on the post) but instead of link to the post, i would want the thumbnail to link to its full image src.

The function is this one:

```
function getImages($num) {
global $more;
$more = 1;
$link = get_permalink(); -> NO IDEA IF HAS ANY SENSE BUT I ALREADY TRIED TO CHANGE THIS ONE TO GET_ATTACHMENT BUT NO LUCK
$content = get_the_content();
$count = substr_count($content, '<img');
$start = 0;
for($i=1;$i<=$count;$i++) {
$imgBeg = strpos($content, '<img', $start);
$post = substr($content, $imgBeg);
$imgEnd = strpos($post, '>');
$postOutput = substr($post, 0, $imgEnd+1);
$postOutput = preg_replace('/width="([0-9]*)" height="([0-9]*)"/', '/width="150"/',$postOutput);
$postOutput = preg_replace('/alignright/', 'aligncenter',$postOutput);
$image[$i] = $postOutput;
}
if(stristr($image[$num],'<img')) { echo '<a href="'.$link.'">'.$image[$num]."</a>"; }
$more = 0;}
```

Does anyone has some clue how can i do this? or other function to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `wp_get_attachment_url($GLOBALS['post']->ID);` instead of `get_permalink();`

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't work, it redirects me to the main page but i found a tricky (maybe messy solution). Using another function to catch the image url and instead the premanet_link i call the function to retriview the link :)

Comment: Could you add the function as an answer if it's the solution? Maybe others can use it later too. You should also try to put `var_dump($GLOBALS['post']->ID);` and `var_dump(get-theID());` inside your function to test if you got all post data set up. Also take a look [here at the bottom of the page][1] to see the functions that get attachments. Maybe you can avoid your callback function completely. [1]http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src

Answer (score 1):

Oh sure, so here is what i did:
I added this other function

```
function catch_that_image() {
  global $post, $posts;
  $first_img = '';
  ob_start();
  ob_end_clean();
  $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
  $first_img = $matches [1] [0];

  if(empty($first_img)){ //Defines a default image
    $first_img = "/images/default.jpg";
  }
  return $first_img;
}
```

And I call it at the $link line, in the getimages function.

```
$link = catch_that_image();
```

Well is messy so i will try your suggestions and see if any of those will work, thanks a lot.